# Can I import a variable from the front end script?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, frontend

I am trying to carry the array of data from one HTML file to another? is that possible and if so how can I do this? Maybe use

here is an example:

First HTML file

```
<script>
    let tmp = <%- result %>;
    let a = ''
    for (const i in tmp){
        a += tmp[i]['PartitionKey'] + ' ' + tmp[i]['company_name']                
    }
    console.log(a);
    export{ a }
</script>
```

Second HTML file

```
<script>
    import { a } from './client.html'
    console.log(a);
</script>
```

Comment: hello @noobdev123, you can't import from html files
rather you can make you scripts a module so they support import and export

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you need to use modules. For example, you have two .js files.
index.js and index2.js.

Code of index.js

```
import { a } from './index2.js';

console.log({ a });
```

Code of index2.js

```
export const a = 10;
```

To use modules in js you have to connect index.js to .html page by `<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>`
And it will only work with http server. To run http server locally you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server